# How to restore the MarkLogic content database index setting from the db backup

Tags: marklogic

I use MarkLogic admin interface to back and restore the content database.

It seems that I could only restore the document content to a newly created database from a db backup file. Somehow the index settings like field/word index etc. could not be restored from the backup file.

I would like to confirm whether it is normal.
(By right, I should have the gradle script to set up the content db. That means I could do **mlUpdateIndex** to reapply the index to the newly created content database.)

If that is true,  it means that I will need to back up the index setting together with the db backup, in order to fully restore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. Your backup has the data, not the database configuration.

The data in the backup will contain the index data - so if you restore into a database with the indexes configured, they will work and you won't need to reindex.

However, if you restore a backup into a database that does not have those indexes defined/configured for that target database, then the indexes will not be available/usable. It won't matter that the index data is present, and if any documents are saved in that database they will start dropping that index information and will be merged out.